# Masked Textbox input jquery

Tags: jquery, maskedtextbox

I am desperately in need of advice.

I am attempting to mask some `textboxes` on a page of mine.  I initially used the `timeEntry plugin` from Tim Wood.

I thought it was working fine, however, it is causing a mixed content message to pop up for people that use `IE 8` on compatibility mode.  I can't figure out what on earth could possible be causing this (everything appears to be loading via https.I watched through fiddler) so I am thinking about using another plugin.

The `MaskedInput plugin` from digital bush does work, but its is lacking for some time masking functionality.

The best I can get is `'99:99'`.  I can't put an `AM` I can't put a `PM` and I can put in invalid times such as `99:99`.

This is a step backwards from the functionality I already had in.  Is there any other plugin that does a good job masking time input?  `Mieomask` seems to be not supported anymore?

Comment: How/why are your visitors using "compatability mode"? As the web developer *you* decide which mode a web page runs in by using the correct DOCTYPE. The visitors should only be using the "compatability mode" button on ancient, broken sites, which I assume yours isn't. Tell your visitors to stop using "compatability mode".

Comment: Actually, for some reason, the people who make the builds for there machines INTENTIONALLY put there browser into compatibility mode.  I just know that they need to be in that mode for some reason, and I am developing this app for them.

Comment: That makes absolutely no sense. Talk with the people in change and find out whats going on.

Comment: So I guess you don't know of any other pluggins that might work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of masked input plugins for jQuery. An extension of digitalBrush's plugin with supposedly more features can be found here: https://github.com/RobinHerbots/jquery.inputmask

Another non-supported plugin recommended by jQuery on their wiki page is here: 
https://github.com/fabiomcosta/jquery-meiomask/wiki

Comment: The second link is broke.  Please update if possible.

Comment: @JoshYates1980 Updated link